# Save data in sqlite date base from a webservice

Tags: android, sqlite, offlineapps

I am new to android and I am facing a problem in one of my applications. The data is coming from a webservice in Json format. I need to save that data in my local database and work with it only through out the application and at the end upload the data back to the server. Basically I need to make an offline app but I am not getting how to start and manage this flow. Any help regrading this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can implement SQLite or realm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem you need to create an offline application using SQLite.

I can't, obviously, write you a full blown SQLIte tutorial but here are some links that might help you in learning how to create such an application.

First of all, in order to persist your data you might want to use [Room](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/room-sqlite-beginner-tutorial-2e725e47bfab), Room is the official **SQLite ORM** created for Android by Google's teams. It will allow you to persist data directly in your database without having to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Then you would need a **JSON** Parser. I use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) which works perfectly fine but many others exists like [JACKSon](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for example.

Now, what you need is an offline synchronization strategies. There are many ways of synchronizing your application with your webservice and there is no miracle solution every application will have a different use case. However here are a couple of links that explain some strategies and when to use them.

[Offline data synchronization, Part1 : Basic strategies to address this critical challenge for mobile apps](https://mobilebusinessinsights.com/2017/09/offline-data-synchronization-part-1-basic-strategies-to-address-this-critical-challenge-for-mobile-apps/)

[Offline data synchronization, Part 2: Advanced strategies to address a crucial challenge for mobile apps](https://mobilebusinessinsights.com/2017/10/offline-data-synchronization-part-2-advanced-strategies-to-address-a-crucial-challenge-for-mobile-apps/)

Then again, your question is too generic to get a specific question. I hope this collection of links will help you in your project.

Cordially,
Matthieu

Comment: Thanks Matthieu Meunier for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

JDXA ORM for Android can help your app save the JSON data in a device-local SQLite database. Using JDXA, you may then work with the saved data in your app through a more convenient POJO object model. You may retrieve the saved/updated data from SQLite in JSON format and send it to the server when needed. You don't need any JSON parsers. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDXA ORM.